# How can I set a fixed cell height?

Tags: notebooks, formatting

I did this often in previous versions of the Mathematica notebook front end.  I would have a cell with lots of raw data, e.g. a very long list.  The list might go on for pages.  I would set the cell to have a fixed cell height using the options inspector.  I could then drag a little box on the bottom of the cell bracket to show only a small fraction, say, the top three and half lines of the input.  (I would cut it off in the middle of a line, showing the top half of the characters in the line, in order to make it clear that only a portion was visible.)

I can no longer find this option in Mathematica 8 (Mac OS X).  Does anyone know if it may be lurking somewhere else?

Answer (score 11):

The cell dimensions are set by the option `CellSize -> {width, height}` which can be found in the category `Cell Options > Inline Cell Options` of the options inspector. One way to get there is to right-click on a cell bracket and select `Properties` near the bottom of the pop-up menu.

**Edit**

This is what the cell looks like in my version of Mathematica (8.0.1 on OS X) after setting `CellSize -> {Automatic, 50}` of the output cell in the options inspector. The little blue square attached to the bottom of the bracket of the output cell is the resize handle.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Were you able to actually change the size of an Input cell with this?

Comment: @BrettChampion yes I was.

Comment: Thanks!  Not only did it set a fixed cell height (leaving the width Automatic), but it exposed the little square on the bracket which allows resizing the cell height with the mouse.

Comment: Apparently the first time I wasn't persitant enough in selecting the option value in the option inspector.

Comment: @Heike this works ok on my computer (OS X with 8.0.4) but maybe paste a screen grab of it in case it is different on different platforms??

Comment: BTW I don't remember the little square at the bottom right appearing before. I don't think I have used `CellSize` since V5. How many versions has that little "resize" square been there?

Comment: @BrettChampion If I want to change an option in the option editor I click on the option value once and hover over it with my mouse cursor  for a few seconds until it goes into edit mode.

Comment: @Heike I had the same problem as Brett; hovering is indeed necessary (OS X at least). Please consider adding this bit to the answer.

Comment: This is a really fantastic option! I didn't know about this! Suggestion to Wolfram: Make this cell-height option easily accessible with the cell's context menu.

Comment: In addition Wolfram should make the cell width usable.  It is unusable in M9.

Answer (score 0):

What about the built-in size limitation? You can either set the maximum output bytes per command using the normal `Preferences` menu, `$OutputSizeLimit = ...`, or `OutputSizeLimit` in the options inspector.

[image]

Comment: The question was about input, not output.

Comment: Oh, pardon me. Should I delete the answer?

Comment: I don't know the protocol here.  Since someone looking through existing questions for an answer to their different question may find your answer useful, perhaps you should leave it.